# Appending and overwriting last 3 days worth of data in a partitioned table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that captures daily order data and overwrites itself every day. As you can imagine - this is getting larger and larger + more expensive!

The obvious solution to this would be to append the order data daily of course.

However, most of our customers order 1-3 days in advance before their order is finalized (lots of fresh products so availability can be volatile). So in the ideal world, the table would append but overwrite the last 3 days worth of data each time?

I don't want to append 1 days worth of data 3 days late either as we need the most up-to-date data as possible. I hope this makes sense!

I'd rate my BQ prowess at a 4/10 so please explain like I'm 5

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you further explain the queries you would like to fire on this table. It make sense to append data every day and not overwrite. There are various performance improvements that can be done on these types of tables such as partition and clustering etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.